# FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Cannot instantiate abstract class App\Modules\ModuleServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, fatal-error

I have used laravel 5.2 for my project.
For a modular approach I have modules in app > modules, and in modules > user.

module > ModuleServiceProvider.php is as below:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules;

use \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
abstract class ModuleServiceProvider extends  ServiceProvider{

  public function boot() {
    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
      $this->package("app/" . $module, $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module);
    }
  }

  public function register() {

    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
      $this->app["config"]->package("app/" . $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/config");

        // Add routes
      $routes = app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/routes.php";
      if (file_exists($routes))
        require $routes;
    }
  }

  public function getModule($args) {
    $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;
    return $module;
  }

}
```

?>

and my LeadServiceProvider.php is like

```
<?php  namespace App\Modules\Lead;

 class LeadServiceProvider extends \App\Modules\ModuleServiceProvider {

public function register()
{
    parent::register("user");
}

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot("user");
}
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */


}
```

i have written it in my app.php providers too

like

> App\Modules\ModuleServiceProvider::class,
>      App\Modules\Lead\LeadServiceProvider::class,

Also written in composer.json too.

but it gives error like

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
>     Cannot instantiate abstract class App\Modules\ModuleServiceProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot instantiate an abstract class. An abstract class MUST be extended by another class. However, it appears that your `ModuleServiceProvider` does not contain any abstract methods, so it shouldn't need to be abstract. Drop the `abstract` keyword from your service provider and that should fix the problem.